# Visual Studio 2015: C++ separate class declaration and implementation

Tags: c++, header-files, implementation, lnk2019

The last version of C++ IDE I was using is VC98, so a lot of things have changed and I'm confused.

I'm trying to create a class `MyParser`. I have its header file `MyParser.h` in `Header Files` in the solution explorer, and the source file `MyParser.cpp` in `Source Files`.

`MyParser.h` looks like below.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

using namespace std;

class MyParser
{
private:
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

public:
    MyParser(string str);
};
```

MyParser.cpp is:

```
#include "MyParser.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MyParser::MyParser(std::string str)
{
    boost::property_tree::read_xml(str, this->pt);
}
```

The `main.cpp` (in a separate project under the same solution) is

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyParser.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string content = "some xml string.....";

    MyParser parser = MyParser(content);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I've got `LNK2019` error:

> unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl
>   MyParser::MyParser(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)"
>   (??0MyParser@@QEAA@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   referenced in function main   test    C:\MySpace\test\test.obj

However, as soon as I move the implementation of the constructor into `MyParser.h`, the error disappears.

Could anyone point it out to me what is wrong with my code/config? Many thanks

Comment: I suspect that `MyParser.cpp` is not part of your project. A quick way to test is to make an intentional error in that file to see if the compiler complains. If it does not then you are not building it..

Comment: Not related to your problem, but don't do `using namespace std`

Comment: @kuro Why is that?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @ChangeMyName could you append a picture of your solution explorer?

Comment: I second @drescherjm. I tried to make a VS2019 project with the three files shown above, and it compiled no problem. Then I deleted the `MyParser.cpp` file from the project and got the exact same LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MyParser::MyParser( ... ) referenced in function _main error as OP does.

Comment: @Frodyne Thanks mate. Then what change should I make in the configs?

Comment: Well, I got that error by deleting the .cpp file from my project, so I guess the fix is to add it again... Try to double-check if you have the file added to your project.